# TFS 2010 Publish Multiple Projects

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, continuous-integration

We've got TFS 2010 set up with continuous integration - Every code checkin results in a build and a publish of the website to a dev server.

We've now got a second project that is referenced by the first. The second is a stand-alone application with a few assemblies. Our website points at one of those assemblies.

I've managed to edit our CI build definition so that `Project2` gets built before `Project1`. `Project1` builds correctly, and finds the references to `Project2`.

What I'd like it to do is also build the stand-alone app for `Project2` at the same time (it isn't visible anywhere in the output from the `Project1` CI build).

Can/should I do this all using a single build definition? Do I need to create multiple build definitions with the same triggers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the second project's source under the workspace section of your build definition.  After that you should be able to select the sln or xxproj for the stand-alone app.

My generally feeling is that having build dependencies across team projects is something of a smell.  I would often elect to put them in the same team project since they seem to depend tightly on one another or make Project1 an opt-in dependency of Project2, but pulling the build output of successful Project1 builds that can be accommodated into Project2.

Just a thought.

Comment: Same team project, different solution. Perhaps I was unclear in my question - Sorry, I didn't even consider using "project" might refer to team project not project-in-a-solution... Do you see any issue with that?

Comment: In addition, it seems I was incorrect in my question in another way - I'd alrady added the Project2 to the workspace (It's a windows service and associated console host) but wasn't seeing the setup.exe for my deployment package in the output. It now looks like the build config doesn't include the deployment package so it's not being built. Thanks for your help, I'd still like to get your answer to my comment above.

Comment: I made the assumption of Project => Team Project based on the two outputs (assembly and stand-alone app) of Project2.  Sorry.  Definitely nothing wrong with what you've done.  What additional work beyond setting project references did you need to do in order for your projects to build in the correct order?  Am I making more assumptions?

Comment: Only to make sure that the wiorkspaces for both were listed and under `Process=>Items To Build`, select both solutions and make sure Project 2 was above Project 1